# PIN authentication on iOS app and then listing all ios apps

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I want to list all my published iOS apps list on my main ios app .

My main iOS app will perform like this: First screen will ask to enter PIN (an authorization code, user will have this code from my other web url ) after validation, next screen will show all published app (published from my developer a/c) of iTunes store. apps will be a free type category, if user click on any specific app, the itunes app should be launch to download that app on device.

Could some one please suggest me , is there any violation of Apple's rule to show my apps in this way authentication to my customers? Will apple reject my app?

Although i was trying to understand a search API of iTunes

http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html

Thanks a lot,

Comment: what would be the point? the iTunes has a public dictionary and everyone can check the applications of a developer without any PIN or password. why do you want your client won't be able to see your applications easily? are you your own enemy? I don't get it. :)

Comment: By this PIN, client wants track his valuable customers and may offer some special to those, who got PIN by registering on the client's website. thx. My concern to prevent from rejection...